# what is difference between declaring variable out of main method and inside main method?

Tags: java

When I was reading book about Java , I saw one example written like this. And I am wondering can I declare variable in outside of main method ? What is difference between declaring variable outside and inside main method? what is " static" 's role in here ? Please some one explain to me? I am new in java.

```
public class Printstuff {
      static int an_integer = 0;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
          int an_integer = 2;
          String[] some_strings = {"Shoes", "Suit", "Tie" };
          an_integer = an_integer - 1;
          some_strings[an_integer] = some_strings[an_integer] +"+++";
          for (int i = 0; i < some_strings.length; i++)
            System.out.println(some_strings[Printstuff.an_integer]);
        }
    }
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**1) Inside vs Outside:**

If you declare your object *inside* a method, it will be visible only in this method. Basically, if you put brackets around it, it's only visible/accessible from within these brackets.

If you declare your object *outside* the method (inside the class), it depends on the *[access modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)*.
By default, it's visible/accessible from within that class and the whole package.

**2) Static**

Static means, that static methods / variables belongs to the class itself, and not to its objects (instances of that class).

Example:

```
public class Members {

  static int memberCount;

  public Members() {
     memberCount++;
  }
}
```

`memberCount` exists only once, no matter how many Objects of the class exists. (even before any object is created!)

Every time you create a new Object of `Members`, `memberCount` is increased. Now you can access it like this: `Members.memberCount`

Comment: So if you only use the variable inside the main method, would I be right in saying that you should declare that variable inside the main method?

Answer (score 4):

Declaring a variable in the main method will make it available only in the main. Declaring a variable outside will make it available to all the methods of the class, including the main method.

Example :

```
public class Foo {
   private String varOne = "Test";

   public void testOne() {
     System.out.println(varOne);
     System.out.println(varTwo); // Error, this variable is available in the testTwo method only
   }

   public void testTwo() {
     String varTwo = "Bar";
     System.out.println(varOne); // Will display "Test"
     System.out.println(varTwo); // Will display "Bar"
   }
}
```

Comment: outside the class  to other classes in the same package too

Comment: @nachokk: just in this case. It depends on the access specifier.

Comment: This code won't compile, as `varOne` is non-static, so can't be accessed from the static `main()` method.

Comment: @bcsb1001 My bad, you're right, I should have been in another planet when I posted it. Thanks for the review, I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm intrigued nobody has mentioned memory matters. Many years ago, instantiating within main() would allocate the variable to the stack, wether instantiating it out ot main would allocate the variable to the heap. Back in those days, systems had very small stacks, so not checking this detail would cause a stack overflow very easilly. I'm not an expert in memory architecture though, I wish somebody could contribute to this subtle detail as applicable to current SW architecture / memory.

Answer (score 1):

There is a scope difference.
And you have to declare it as static because your main function is static so it allows you to use only static variables.
Variable which declares inside main method would only be used inside main method only.

Now you might wondering that why I need to have main method as static!!!
As any application in java will run from main method so it can be called by class name only without creating any object so we are defining it as static. All static method can call with class reference, no object needed.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is now your `an_integer` has more scope.

Example if you have another method.

```
public class Printstuff {
      static int an_integer = 0;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
          int an_integer = 2;
          String[] some_strings = {"Shoes", "Suit", "Tie" };
          an_integer = an_integer - 1;
          some_strings[an_integer] = some_strings[an_integer] +"+++";
          for (int i = 0; i < some_strings.length; i++)
            System.out.println(some_strings[Printstuff.an_integer]);
        }

      public void anotherMethod(){
         an_integer++;
      }


    }
```

As you declared

`<default package> int an_integer=0;`

**All clases in the same package has access to this variable.**

Comment: You are welcome, consider accepting any answer and upvoting those who let you understand :)

Answer (score 1):

What you refer to is the scope of a variable.

Variables inside methods are only accessible inside this method, ie `an_integer` inside the `main`-method cannot be referenced outside the `main` method. Variables can even have narrower scopes, for exammple inside loops. The classic iterating variable of a `for` loop is only avaiable inside its loop, afterwards its gone.

Variables outside methods are called fields. It depends on its access modifier where it can be seen. `Private` fields for example are only avaiable inside this class, `public` fields can be accessed from anywhere (other access modifiers are `protected` and none, which falls back on a default). Basically, you can use a field inside a class to access its value from every method inside this class, this, however, might be dangerous if multiple threads access the same instance of a class, but this is a whole other story.

A field and a local variable may have the same name, which can lead to confusion. I would generally prefer not to do this, or, maybe better, always refer to fields with a `this` accessor. I am not entierly sure whether there is a preference of local variables versus fields of the same name, but I would guess local variables are of higher priority when determining which one was meant.

`Static` fields now mean that this variable does not belong to an instance of a class, but to the class itself. `Static` fields (and methods) can be read (or invoked) without having to initialize the class first. An example could be a standardvalue of a class, or maybe a factorymethod (if its a method). `Static` fields may also come in handy for constants, together with the `final` modifier. A `public final static` field is pretty much a global constant.