# Add a dynamic name to file

Tags: java, file, for-loop, output, jfilechooser

I made a button that creates txt files, here all works fine.

But the problem is when I create the first: TXT file, I dont know what I need or what I need to do, to continue creating TXT files, dynamically.

Here is my code:

```
int c;
c = 0;
c++;
String Name = "TXT" + c +".txt";
File TXT = new File(Name);
TXT.createNewFile();
```

This create a: TXT1.txt
But not creating a TXT2.txt, TXT3.txt, etcetera.

I want increment the number dynamically. Thank you for read.

Comment: Can you show us the code you expect to create TXT2.txt because your current code always starts at `c = 0`

Comment: The first time I try with the count as: 1, but dont works. So I put the count as: 0. Just to test.

Comment: So next time the count needs to start as 1 and then 2 etc.  If you used a loop it would do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Inside vs Outside:
>
> If you declare your object inside a method, it will be visible only in
>   this method. Basically, if you put brackets around it, it's only
>   visible/accessible from within these brackets.
>
> If you declare your object outside the method (inside the class), it
>   depends on the access modifier. By default, it's visible/accessible
>   from within that class and the whole package.
>
> 2) Static
>
> Static means, that this Object/Variable belongs to the class itself,
>   and not to its objects

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17700393/4985572)

To simulate the button click, I made this small code:

```
package main.application;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    private static int incrementFileName = 1;
    private static final String PATH = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //Each time the button is pressed.
        for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
        {
            incrementFileName++;
            buttonClicked();
        }
    }

    private static void buttonClicked() throws IOException
    {
        String Name = "TXT" + incrementFileName +".txt";
        File TXT = new File(PATH + Name);
        TXT.createNewFile();
    }
}
```

As you can see, you need to declare the `incrementFileName` (your `c`) outside the method which is used to create a `new File`, and increment it each time a button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you so much, finally works. And thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a for loop and exclude the counter like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < yourMaximumRun; ++i)
{

    String Name = "TXT" + i +".txt";
    File TXT = new File(Name);
    try
    {
        TXT.createNewFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are going to use a for loop, use the int from the loop to increment

Comment: True, I changed it

Answer (score 1):

If this is the code in your method, c always gets initiated with 0 and incremented to 1.

If you hit the button again, c will again be initiated with 0 and incremented. You need to persist your c somewhere outside of the method instead of re-initializing it everytime.